# SQLException: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am most likely missing something simple here since I am pretty new to this but I cannot figure this out. 
I have a C# application that takes some user-entered data and updates a SQL Server database. One of the database fields I am updating is called "TransectLength" and has a datatype of 'decimal(5,1)'. The SQL looks like this:

```
string updateSQL = "UPDATE " + table1 + " SET TransectLength = NULLIF(@tl, '') WHERE ObjectID = @oid";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, conn);
```

The parameter @tl:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tl", dr["TransectLength"]);
```

dr is a DataRow. dr["TransectLength"] has a value of 2.5 and type is object{decimal}. 
When I try:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get the SQL Exception Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
Please see below for the parameter @tl. The SqlDbType is Decimal. If I enter nothing for TransectLength (i.e. dr["TransectLength"] value is {}) then the update query works just fine and appropriately enters a sql NULL value. 
I also tried this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tl", Convert.ToDecimal(dr["TransectLength"]));
```

But nothing changed. 
Thanks for your help.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `NULLIF(@tl, '')` to `ISNULL(@tl, 0.0)`

Comment: or `NULLIF(@t1, 0.0)`. The point being that you can't default to a `varchar` value if your column data type is `decimal`.

Comment: ah! Beautiful! Thank you so much. I knew it had to be something simple.